# Get taxonomy name of current post

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms, hierarchical, single

Hierarchical taxonomy of custom post type 'projects' > 'projects_category'.

Two example 'projects_category' hierarchies would be:

> Big Corporates > 1st Company Name > A Post Title
>
> Small Business > 2nd Company Name > Another Post Title

I can get **'1st Company Name'** with the following:

```
<?php $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'projects_category');foreach($terms as $term){echo $term->name;} ?>
```

How can I display 'Big Corporates' or 'Small Business' as appropriate in single.php ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've marked up anu's answer and get_ancestors explanation, however this is how I solved it:

```
<?php 
$terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'projects_category', array('orderby' => 'term_id', 'order' => 'ASC') );
    if ( !empty( $terms ) ) :
    $project = array();
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $project[] = $term->name;
}
    echo '<h1>'.$project[0].'</h1>';
    echo '<h2>'.$project[1].'</h2>';
    endif;
    ?>
```

Answer (score 5):

[get_ancestors()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_ancestors) should do what you need:

So, you should do something like this:

```
$ancestors = get_ancestors($term_id, 'projects_category)
```

Comment: But does get_ancestors() work with custom post type? It doesn't seem to be working for me...

Comment: Your question doesn't really have anything to do with CPT's - it's about custom taxonomies. Also, check you're on WP 3.1 or above

Comment: I'm on latest version of WP 3.2.1. I stated this is for custom post types in the first paragraph of my question but maybe it is more about custom taxonomies? Either way the answer still eludes us.

Comment: You may be using CPTs, but what you're looking for is a way to traverse a custom taxonomy hierarchy - that's what 'terms' are - items in a taxonomy that you can attach to a post object (whether that post object is a normal post, a page, or a custom post type)

Comment: I'd tried this <?php get_ancestors( $post->ID, 'projects_category' ); ?> which returned nothing. Can you elaborate on your answer at all?

Comment: I added an example of usage in my answer - you're using the post ID, when you should be using the term id. This is taxonomy, not custom post,

Comment: So that'll work in single.php ? It doesn't seem to produce anything when I tried it. As I said in my question I need this in the single not taxonomy template.

Comment: @anu let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/793/discussion-between-andy-and-anu)

Comment: Has nothing to do with the template you're using. Get the term id that you're interested in, and pass it to get_ancestors. The code you posted in your question gets the term name, so get the term id from that, and use it as an input into get_ancestors. You're trying to find the parent term. Not the parent post. Not sure how to make this any clearer.

Comment: Thanks for trying to explain, its not working yet but do you mean something like this: <?php $term = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'projects_category' ); $term_id = $term[0]->name; $ancestors = get_ancestors($term_id, 'projects_category'); echo $ancestors; ?>

Comment: $term[0]->name isn't the term id - you should use $term[0]->term_id

Comment: Currently only my sub level taxonomy term (1st Company Name) is 'checked' in the admin area. Does my top level taxonomy term (Big Corporates) also need to be 'checked' in the admin panel for it to be retrievable in this way?

Comment: Try it and see!

Comment: When both are checked, get_ancestors does return both category and parent category in alphabetic order. Is there a way to extract the category names from top and lower levels separately? So one can be put into a H1 and the other in a H2.

Answer (score 1):

If you read this article on custom post types it should help: **[Revisiting Custom Post Types, Custom Taxonomies, and Permalinks](http://mondaybynoon.com/2011/05/20/revisiting-custom-post-types-taxonomies-permalinks-slugs/)**

Comment: It didn't help, I saw nothing in there that showed how to get the root taxonomy name in the single template. In the comments there are people asking how to do it but no solution was posted. I think this is not easily achieved for a custom post type.

Comment: Ahh, I see you mean,  sorry I don't think I have the answer to that problem either.

Answer (score 0):

This is very good code for get taxonomy title in detail page or single page in custom post type in WordPress,

```
<?php $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'projects_category');foreach($terms as $term){echo $term->name;} ?>
```