# Echo taxonomy term meta on author.php

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, terms

What is the correct way to output taxonomy term meta associated with an object?

Specifically...

I have registered a custom taxonomy, "firms".
This is attached only to "Users" (not something WordPress natively supports, but accomplished thanks to the [LH User Taxonomies](https://wordpress.org/plugins/lh-user-taxonomies/) plugin).

Term meta for each "firm" are company details - a few dozen fields include "firm_geo_city" and "firm_social_twitter" etc, in addition to standard name, slug and description.

Each User can only belong to one "firm", since "`single_value`" is set to "true" in my taxonomy registration.

My goal is, on each user's author.php profile page, to output each of the term meta details of the firm s/he belongs to.

How do I output these details? I don't understand. I have investigated `get_term_meta`, but have no found success.

Answer (score 1):

Via [a related question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/22802/get-taxonomy-name-of-current-post/23134#23134), I discovered [`wp_get_object_terms`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_object_terms) - it seems it is that which I need.

So I am now using code like...

```
      $firm_terms = wp_get_object_terms( $curauth->ID,  'firm' );

      if ( ! empty( $firm_terms ) ) {
        if ( ! is_wp_error( $firm_terms ) ) {
                foreach( $firm_terms as $term ) {
                    echo '<a href="' . get_term_link( $term->slug, 'firm' ) . '">' . esc_html( $term->name ) . '</a>';
                }
        }
      }
```

... This works okay.

Although I wish I knew how and whether to take the `foreach` out of this. I'm not sure that I need this here. Ideas welcome.