# How to display taxonomy term custom meta (using wp_get_object_terms?)?

Tags: taxonomy, terms, taxonomy-meta

I am attempting to feed term meta values from my custom taxonomy, "firm"/"firms", on to a User profile page at `author.php`.

Users are attached to this taxonomy thanks to the [LH User Taxonomy](https://wordpress.org/plugins/lh-user-taxonomies/) plugin. I need to display term meta fields for the firm to which s/he belongs.

[So far](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/273280/echo-taxonomy-term-meta-on-author-php), I have managed to find `wp_get_object_terms useful`. This code echos the **slug** and **name** meta of the taxonomy term; **description** also works...

```
      $firm_terms = wp_get_object_terms( $curauth->ID,  'firm' );

      if ( ! empty( $firm_terms ) ) {
        if ( ! is_wp_error( $firm_terms ) ) {
                foreach( $firm_terms as $term ) {
                    echo '<a href="' . get_term_link( $term->slug, 'firm' ) . '">' . esc_html( $term->name ) . '</a>';
                }
        }
      }
```

It works, it seems.

However, I have only managed to output those three standard term meta fields - name, slug and description. In addition, I also have a couple of dozen other term meta fields thanks to putting an Advanced Custom Fields field group on the Edit User page, storing extra "firm" details. These are intended for output but they do not show, using code like this (fragment):

```
      foreach( $firm_terms as $term ) {
        echo $term->firm_social_twitter_handle;
      }
```

Is `wp_get_object_terms` only built to show **name**, **slug** and **description**? Is there a way I can also echo out fields like **firm_social_twitter_handle** and **firm_geo_city**?

Do I need to use a combination of that and `get_terms`, or something else? I had earlier found some success using `get_terms`, but couldn't manage to constrain it to only take meta from the taxonomy term to which the User is attached, like I can using the above `wp_get_object_terms` code.

Comment: The extra details are attached to the term or do you mean are attached to an user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If those extra fields are saved on Edit User page you should get them with [get_user_meta](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta) function:

```
$social_twitter_handle = get_user_meta( $curauth->ID, 'firm_social_twitter_handle', true );
```

If those extra fields are attached to each term you can use [get_term_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_meta/) function:

```
$firm_terms = wp_get_object_terms( $curauth->ID,  'firm' );

if ( ! empty( $firm_terms ) ) {
    if ( ! is_wp_error( $firm_terms ) ) {
            foreach( $firm_terms as $term ) {
                echo '<a href="' . get_term_link( $term->slug, 'firm' ) . '">' . esc_html( $term->name ) . '</a>';
                $firm_social_twitter_handle = get_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'firm_social_twitter_handle', true );
                echo $firm_social_twitter_handle;
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: dbeja, the fields are in taxonomy terms. I presume I prefix that `foreach` code with `$firm_terms = wp_get_object_terms( $curauth->ID,  'firm' );`? Now I have the reverse problem - whilst I can echo out fields like `firmsocial_twitter_handle`, I am unable to find the standard `name`, `slug` and `description` using the same method.

Comment: No, you keep what you had for the other fields. This was just to get those extra fields. What function are you using? get_user_meta or get_term_meta?

Comment: I changed the code with your example

Comment: `get_term_meta`, as that's the info I want to echo out (albeit on to an author.php whose use is under this taxonomy). From your example, I now see the difference between echoing the standard `name` term value and an extra field like `firm_social_twitter_handle` - whilst you have to find `firm_social_twitter_handle` using `get_term_meta`, `name` (and `slug` and `description`) are available much more easily, using `$term->name`. Sounds like `name`, `slug` and `description` have more a _value_ than a _meta_. Is that fair to say?

Comment: Yes. What happens is that name and slug are columns of the same table of terms. When you get a term by ID you have in the same row name and slug, they always exist. Other fields are custom fields and can be whatever you want and any number of them, so they are saved in a different database table with a relation on the term ID. You can check WP database: https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description

Comment: This is excellent and appreciated answering.